# Want to add "More from developer" option in Android

Tags: android, google-play

There are few apps of mine is in the play store. Now I want only my application in app suggestion tab on play app when some one open my application

So I've created a Developer Account for the Google Play Store and have uploaded a few apps. 
My concern is I want only my application as suggestion.. I have seen it some apps like  "More from developer", But now my apps are not listing is there any way to make it possible, I want a similar tab as below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well subsequent to these are your applications you can essentially hard-code the symbols into a RecyclerView or ListView alongside a connection prompting Google Play. This truly doesn't require an outsider library as it should effectively be possible independent from anyone else.

On the off chance that you truly need to consider future extensiveness, you could utilize a cloud stage like parse where you store the names of various applications as parse articles alongside a connection and a picture (logo). At that point you could compose a custom connector for your rundown which takes the parse objects from your cloud, and populates itself with the logo,link,title,etc.

> This is really a matter of comfort and preference rather than finding
>   a library to do this for you. If you need help, feel free to ask, and
>   good luck!

for Moving to perticular application of yours use below code

```
try {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

You can show a `Dialog` asking if the user cares to check some of your other apps with two available options: `yes` and `no`. If the user chooses 'no', close the dialog, if he chooses 'yes' - redirect him/her to the following url:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id={Your-Google-Account-Name}
```

Comment: +1 for the Parse option. OP can also store the package name. That way she she can use `market://` and take users directly to the app listing in PlayStore.

Comment: Yes that depends on OP, how he/she wants to perform it. But there is no library available to do this operations :)

Comment: Sorry, This was not my requirement actually I have added a screen shot I want a similar tab in play store